# Show view from storyboard chain

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a chain in storyboard and I want to start (for example) second view when I have first launching app. I have some code, which only work in

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

method, if I put it in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

method it's not work,

the code which show my other view is:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someId"];
[vc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
```

How can I show view, which have place in chain in storyboard when app have first launching?

Answer (score 1):

Try your code in 
`-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`.

For further information on the iOS viewcontroller lifecycle head over to [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a navigation controller, you can simply push the second view onto the navigation stack. If you are not using a navigation controller, then you could force a segue to the next view from the loading.

Comment: I use viewController and button (UIBarButtonItem), when I push on it the navigation controller is showing.