# Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discourage

Tags: ios, xcode, amslidemenu

I'm using xcode 5.1.1 with storyboard. I have a button on main menu and it pops to another view controller with this code

```
VC *secondVC = [[VC alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:secondVC animated:YES completion: nil];
```

And there I have back button with this code

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
```

And when I pop to secondVC xcode gives me is error:

> Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discourage `<UINavigationController: 0x8c94510>`.

I'm also having problem with rotation, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning :-Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890761/warning-presenting-view-controllers-on-detached-view-controllers-is-discourage)

Answer (score 19):

This warning will come up if if you are trying to push, present or pop view controllers in viewWillAppear. I don't know what is in your code so it's tough to identify your problem but try using this if you are trying to show new views in viewWillAppear.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod)
               withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

Answer (score 11):

Present the controller from `viewDidAppear:` instead.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: Also, this briefly shows the first view controller which seems to be unintended.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into a similar situation while attempting to present an UIAlertController from viewWillAppear. Since performSelector does not exist in Swift, I wrapped my call this way:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()), {
    presentYourVCHere;
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Try pushing from rootVC:

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLER animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

try calling the same action in viewDidAppear.
this warning is due to when we present any view in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method.

so do this in 
          override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) { ...
}

Comment: I called in viewDidAppear() but it does not help @UIResponder

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to present the `UIViewController` from a `splitViewController`.

This is what solved my issue:

```
self.view.window.rootViewController.present(yourViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I found a similar solution with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131205/how-to-find-topmost-view-controller-on-ios

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wonder how you could do this using swift (even can be used in Objective C), following code help me to overcome the above issue. Use this code inside the viewDidLoad()

```
var dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
         //this place to call segue or manually load the view. 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when presenting a UIAlertController from a 
UIViewController (vc2) nested inside another UIViewController (vc1)

I solved it like so:

```
[vc1 addChildViewController:vc2]
```

After doing that I could present UIAlertController from vc2 without any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

in case this error happens from popup view controller you need to call the code for show the alert controller directly from parent view using delegation.  For example in your parent view controller:

```
-(void) showAlertError: (YourClass *) whateverParameter {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Your Title"
                                                                       message:@"Your message"
                                                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];
        [alert addAction:defaultAction];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}
```

And in your child view:

```
- (IBAction)btnDone:(id)sender{
    [self.delegate showAlertError:self];
}
```

Comment: confirm, year 2017, swift 3, iOs 10, issue is the same while opening mail popup from sidemenu, and only one working solution is to delegate to main VC. No dispatch needed though.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers helped me. And here the code which I used to resolve the issue.

```
let topViewController = (self.navigationController?.viewControllers.last)! as UIViewController
topViewController.presentViewController(secondView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope this will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Please click below link for the same issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43268601/2226399