# Warning: Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-warnings, uialertcontroller

My situation with this is different than every other example I have been able to find on here.  I have a tab based app.  On one of the tabs a user is able to press a button that downloads several files from a web server all at once.

I make use of NSOperation to perform each of these downloads so that I can utilize the built in dependencies.  The downloads are all occurring on a background thread so the app remains responsive.  When the final download is complete I put an alertController on screen letting the user know that they are complete.

If the user has selected a different tab when the alert controller is presented I get the warning: "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged"

If they are still on the same tab that started the downloads then I don't get the warning.  I tried replacing:

```
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

with

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but the result is that the alertController is never presented.

I am presenting the alertController on the main thread.

I have no way of predicting what tab view controller the user will be on when the downloads complete, and would really like to get rid of this warning.

I am developing on macOS and Xcode 8 with Obj-C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning :-Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890761/warning-presenting-view-controllers-on-detached-view-controllers-is-discourage)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to delegate the result of the download to the top-level view controller, which sounds like your `UITabBarController`.  The `UITabBarController` certainly [knows which tab is selected](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621172-selectedviewcontroller), or it can present the alert on itself.

Comment: Awesome!!  This line of code solved my problem:  [self.tabBarController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 2):

Write to fix **warning** on presenting navigation controller or VC from current VC:

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To fix **crash** while dismissing view controller:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

***OR***

If you present a view from a childViewController it will give you that warning. To avoid this, you can present a view on childViewController's parent.

```
[self.parentViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```