# Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, model-view-controller

I am trying to move the new view controller from my current view controller i am using the following code to do this

```
self.loginView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LOGIN"];
[self presentViewController:self.loginView animated:NO completion:nil];
```

This code works fine for the iOS 8 but in iOS 7(iPhone) it is not working. Can someone help me so get rid of this error?

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error when running this in the iOS 7 simulator?

Comment: Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

Comment: Sounds like this might do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890761/warning-presenting-view-controllers-on-detached-view-controllers-is-discourage

Comment: I have tried this but not working for me

Comment: If you'd like to upload a small sample project that demonstrates the issue it would be easier to troubleshoot. It's difficult to diagnose the problem without being able to see what you're working with.

Comment: This code is working fine on the iPad with iOS 7 but not with the iPhone on iOs 7.
On touch of button i am just moving to next view controller nothing more than that i am doing

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use 
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.loginView animated:NO completion:nil];

Comment: what is that? Why are you answering with this code if you don't know the view hierarchy?

Comment: So i said ,please try . Maybe it's useful :)