# App tried to present an active controller modally - exception?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios7

There is one button on my navigation bar. When I clicked on it, it used to open an `alertsheet` with a search option. Clicking on the search button would trigger a popover with a `tableView` and a `textField` in it.

Searching something in the `textField` and clicking on the search button would populate the `tableView` with data coming from the server. But after loading all the data, it crashes with this exception.

Exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller Irving. SearchViewController: 0x7fe655d3c7d0.'

[This is the popover view-link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFnDb.png)

I am very new to IOS swift and I have seen other answers, but I was unable to get those things. I have refered below links, but I am still unable to get those things. Please help me out with this, thanks in advance. Give me brief idea about this.

[How to prevent present modally an active controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024812/how-to-prevent-present-modally-an-active-controller)

My code :

```
let Search = UIAlertAction(title: "Search", style: .default) { (action) in
     let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "search_popover") as! SearchViewController
     self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
     popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
     self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
     popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
sheet.addAction(Search)
sheet.addAction(cancel_button)
present(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I think your controller is already present (loaded)

Comment: @user3344236 Can you please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: You can set all within single UIViewController and present that modally without being much troublesome.