# Xcode-7.0.1: Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7

I have a UITabBarController in storyboard which has a navigation controller as one of the tab bar items. When I try to do `[self presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:NULL]` on the root view-controller of my navigation controller, the application stops responding and I get the following error/warning on the console

```
2015-10-16 18:21:40.175 My_App[1224:488753] Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <MyViewController: 0x16512b00>.
```

I am experiencing this issue only when the app is built using Xcode-7.0.1 and run on iOS-9. It works perfectly on iOS-8 with Xcode-7.0.1 and even on iOS-9 when built using Xcode 6.4.

**Edit:**

This is my view controller hierarchy just before I present `myVC` from `myRootViewController`.

```
(lldb) po [UIViewController _printHierarchy]
<LibraryTabBarController 0x7f91935e9660>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7f9195841420>
   | <UINavigationController 0x7fe46b863200>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fe46b54c6a0>
   |    | <MyRootViewController 0x7fe46b47aa40>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x7fe46b66f8a0>
   | <MyOtherViewController 0x7f919580fd80>, state: disappeared, view:  (view not loaded)
```

Comment: Maybe alteration in this response could help:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21003988/3726037

Comment: You must be adding `self.view` as a subview to another `UIViewController` and then from `self` controller you are trying the present `myVC`. Just add `self` as a child controller before adding the subview and this warning will go away.

Answer (score 2):

The error message suggests that the view controller you're presenting from is not (yet) in the view controller hierarchy. Perhaps you've instantiated a view controller to which `self` refers and haven't yet added it to the tab bar's collection of view controllers. Perhaps you're trying to do this in `prepareForSegue`. Perhaps you did `addSubview` for a child view controller but neglected to do the necessary view controller containment calls (e.g. `addChildViewController`). It could be a lot of issues. I'd suggest you describe a bit about how `self`, itself, was presented, before we worry about how it presents other view controllers.

If you think that `self` is already in the view controller hierarchy, I'd suggest we confirm that. Run the app from Xcode and before you hit this line of code that presents `VC`, press the debugger's pause button:

[image]

And at the `(lldb)` prompt, enter:

```
po [UIViewController _printHierarchy]
```

Or, if you pause in a Swift frame, you could enter:

```
expr -l objc++ -O -- [UIViewController _printHierarchy]
```

And you should see something like:

```
(lldb) po [UIViewController _printHierarchy]
<UITabBarController 0x7fcae1c19740>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fcae1c26730>
   | <UINavigationController 0x7fcae3012c00>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fcae1d10b90>
   |    | <MyApp.ViewController 0x7fcae1c19cd0>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x7fcae1c2c470>
   | <SecondViewController 0x7fcae1e1b860>, state: disappeared, view:  (view not loaded)
```

Confirm that whatever view controller `self` refers to in your question appears in this view controller hierarchy. If so, show us your view controller hierarchy and which one `self` is.

Comment: up vote for teaching me `po [UIViewController _printHierarchy]`

Comment: @Gandalf - And up-vote to you for pointing out the possibility that he might have failed to do the view controller containment calls.

Comment: @Rob - thanks for your responses. I have added to my question, the view controller hierarchy that you'd suggested and though everything seems fine to me, surely I am missing something here.