# Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In my app when I am moving from the tableview footer section to another view controller it's moving fine but after moving  the app will crash. Afterwards I'm getting this error.

[image]

Here is my Code:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView == educateTbl) //here you can make a decision
    {
        float footerWidth = 150.0f;
        float padding = 10.0f;
        UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, footerWidth, 50.0)];
        footerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

        UIButton *addEdu = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(padding, 0, footerWidth - 2.0f * padding, 44.0f)];
        addEdu.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        addEdu.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

        addEdu.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:23/255.0 green:186/255.0 blue:239/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [addEdu setTitle:@"Add Education" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [addEdu addTarget:self action:@selector(addEducation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [addEdu setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//set the color this is may be different for iOS 7
        addEdu.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30); //set some large width to ur title
        [footerView addSubview:addEdu];
        return footerView;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)addEducation:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    AddEducationViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddEducationVC"];
    [self presentViewController:ivc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: post also the error , what error is coming

Comment: You must keep `ivc` with strong pointer.

Comment: @AayushKatiyar. see my updated question.

Comment: have u written anything inside addEducationViewController.h and .m file

Comment: u have to use navigation controller without navigation u can not solve this error

Comment: @AayushKatiyar. i will try and inform u.

Comment: @AayushKatiyar. not working with navigation controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning :-Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890761/warning-presenting-view-controllers-on-detached-view-controllers-is-discourage)

Answer (score 0):

`[self presentViewController:ivc animated:YES completion:nil];`

try to change for :

`[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:deleAlert animated:YES completion:nil];`