# Navigation between view controllers is not worked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Getting this kind of errors while moving the controller from one screen to other.

> Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning :-Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890761/warning-presenting-view-controllers-on-detached-view-controllers-is-discourage)

Comment: How you are presenting your view controller? add that code in question!

Comment: can you show ur try code or storyboard scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

when everything is finished, you can just call :

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

you can also refer this link : 
[Warning :-Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890761/warning-presenting-view-controllers-on-detached-view-controllers-is-discourage)

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me

Display your viewController on its parent as given below:

```
[self.YourParentViewController presentViewController:yourPresentingViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And dismiss like this:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```