# MFMailComposeViewController does not dismiss

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement `MFMailComposeViewController` in case of sending the emails from within my application. The problem is that after presenting `MFMailComposeViewController` it is not dismissing by "Cancel" or "Send" buttons, just a bit scrolls up.

Here is the presenting of it:

```
func mailButtonDidPressed {
        let emailTitle = "Test email"
        let messageBody = "some body bla bla bla"
        let toRecipents = "email@gmail.com"

        let emailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
        emailComposer.setSubject(emailTitle)
        emailComposer.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
        emailComposer.setToRecipients([toRecipents])
        emailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self
        self.presentViewController(emailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

and dismissing delegate code:

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    switch (result) {
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        print("You sent the email.")
        break
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        print("You saved a draft of this email")
        break
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        print("You cancelled sending this email.")
        break
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        print("Mail failed:  An error occurred when trying to compose this email")
        break
    default:
        print("An error occurred when trying to compose this email")
        break
    }

    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have surfed through the StackOverflow and other services like this and could not find any answer.

Comment: does **didFinishWithResult** is called..? i mean have you added delegate?

Comment: I tested your code. It's working just fine.

Comment: kind of a miracle, because it still doesn't work

Comment: Try testing it on an actual device if you haven't.

Comment: I do test it on my iPhone, not on Simulator

Answer (score 13):

## Swift 5

Remember to add **both** delegates:

```swift
emailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self
emailComposer.delegate = self
```

If you only add one, it won't dismiss. Also make sure to implement the delegate method:

```swift
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Works for me like a charm! Thanks Ken.

Answer (score 9):

If anybody's having this problem in Swift 3.0, I think there might be two methods for MFMailComposeViewController that look similar to the CORRECT method.

Make sure you are using this method

```
  func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: @HusseinAlBehary yay!

Comment: This worked for me too! For some reason apple's example here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller wasn't

Answer (score 6):

for swift 3 you have to add

```
        composer.mailComposeDelegate = self as MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved writing in this way removing the `completion` in this way:

```
extension UIViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    func sendEmail() {
      //send email
    }

    public func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `mailComposeControllermailComposeController`is a function of the same class as `mailButtonDidPressedmailButtonDidPressed`, it should be its instance that dismiss the MFMailComposeViewController, so

`self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

instead of

`controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

Comment: I've got exactly the same result

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the delegate :

```
emailComposer.delegate = self
```

your code should be like this :

```
func mailButtonDidPressed {
        ...

        let emailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
       emailComposer.delegate = self 

...
    }
```

Comment: `emailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self` I can see this in OPs code.

Comment: I'm not sure 100% but it's not the same

Comment: emailComposer.delegate = self  this delegate should conform UINavigationControllerDelegate, are sure that I should conform to that protocol in my view controller?

Comment: Please can you add debug point at `controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` and show me what you got in debugger ?

Comment: 2016-08-09 16:32:01.806 MyProject[2899:1110844] Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged < MyProject.ViewController: 0x13096a470>.
You cancelled sending this email.

Comment: are you using swift 2 or 3 ?

Comment: @user3224534 It looks like you are presenting view controller from the child view controller. can you try [presenting from parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890761/warning-presenting-view-controllers-on-detached-view-controllers-is-discourage) ?

Comment: double checked what I've done, after GoodSp33d hint, there was a problem with my navigation flow, thank you, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the answer was extremely simple.  Make sure to include

```
MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
```

in the top as when you are listing your inheritances, and then include the stuff from the other answers.