# Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged, when reloads collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have View controller which has collection view, on 1st time load everything works fine, whenever i call collectionview.rloadData() with updated data, it crashes and gives error as mentioned in quesn title, Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890761/warning-presenting-view-controllers-on-detached-view-controllers-is-discourage

Comment: Can you throw some piece of code at us.

Comment: This is just a warning. This is not the reason for the crash. Submit more code