# I received an error when presenting a modal view controller. It says my view controller is detached. Any solution?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, mfslidemenu

Error : "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged ."

```
HomeView *objHomeView = [[HomeView alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeView" bundle:nil];
objNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objHomeView];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:objHomeView];
self.sideMenu.navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
self.window.rootViewController = [self sideMenu].navigationController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: can you please add the code, that you have tried

Comment: In your code when you presenting viewcontroller ?? it's seems that you are just setting rootviewcontroller.

Comment: thanx @KetanParmar but  i already set rootviewcontroller to myhome view.

Comment: i got the solution thank you

Comment: If you got the solution, could you add the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:objHomeView];
```

To

```
NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:objNav];
```

Comment: This error may occur when you are trying to present view controller before view actually did appear. You can check this thread for more info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890761/warning-presenting-view-controllers-on-detached-view-controllers-is-discourage