# Swift Unable to present view controller from top to bottom

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, catransition

In my application I have to present the screen from Top to bottom and I have tried below code its giving the same normal presenting style.

```
        let screen = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Screen1p5") as? Screen1p5
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.5
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
        view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
        self.present(screen!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For that you need to set `subtype` of `CATransition` to [`kCATransitionFromBottom`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/kcatransitionfrombottom) and for batter animation set `animated` to `false` with `present(_:animated:completion:)`.

```
let screen = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Screen1p5") as? Screen1p5
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.5
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
self.present(screen!, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

For dismiss set `subtype` of `CATransition` to `kCATransitionFromTop`.

```
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.5
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
self.dismiss(animated: false)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will try and let you know.

Comment: It is worked fine but while dismissing view it should dismiss from bottom to top direction, not top to bottom again, Will you please tell me how to dismiss the presented controller from bottom to top.

Comment: That was nice solution its working fine . . While presenting controller in log i'm getting message like "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged" will it effect to application.

Comment: @MaheshNarla Check this link for that warning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890761/warning-presenting-view-controllers-on-detached-view-controllers-is-discourage

Comment: yes bro its helped me and i updated my code as follows then warning message disappeared 
 self.view.window?.rootViewController?.present(screen!, animated: false, completion: nil) Thank you again

Comment: @MaheshNarla Welcome mate :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132181/discussion-between-mahesh-narla-and-nirav-d).

Answer (score 4):

Just changed it `transition.subtype` to `kCATransitionFromBottom`

> transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom

For dismiss the controller.

```
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.5
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Please find the below GIF representation.

[image: GIF]

> If you are using the .XIB then please find the below code.

For present the controller.

```
let newController = NewViewController(nibName: "NewView", bundle: nil)
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.5
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
self.present(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

For dismiss the controller. It is the same code as above.

```
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.5
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: @Ramakrishna sharma It is worked fine and  while dismissing view it should dismiss from bottom to top direction, not top to bottom again, Will you please tell me how to dismiss the presented controller from bottom to top.

Comment: Update the answer please review it.

Comment: Thanks @MaheshNarla and up-voting the answer.

Comment: Will you please tell me how to present xib to viewcontroller

Comment: It means that you are using xib instead of Storyboard, right.

Comment: Yes as per requirement i have to use xib instead of storyboard for one view controller

Comment: For this i have rised another separate question The issue was resolved  I got the same answer from there, anyway thank you bro for your response

Comment: why does it show a flash screen of black color? I am encountering the same issue but unable to resolve it. Can anybody help? I tried putting tint color to white in appDelegate file but it didn't help.

Comment: hey @RamkrishnaSharma I really hate when the view controller in the back turn to black in last moment of the transition , how can I fix this , I try to set the view controller modalPresentationStyle property to .overCurrentContext but it's not working