# Present transparent view controller on top of another viewcontroller with custom animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to present a view controller on top of a view using the following code

```
HubViewController* vc = [HubViewController socialHubViewController];
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 3.0;
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
    [vc.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:^{
        NSLog(@"vc: presented");
    }];
```

Does not seem to work. Any help appreciated.

Comment: That is not how to do a custom animation on presentation. And you surely know by now that "does not seem to work" is not a meaningful problem statement. You have explained neither what you expect / desire nor what actually happens.

Comment: oops i found this code in a stackoverflow post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440934/swift-unable-to-present-view-controller-from-top-to-bottom

Comment: Well it's totally wrong. Who lives by the copy and paste dies by the copy and paste.

Comment: But they are saying on the post that is working...i thought i was doing something wrong...that is why i asked.

Comment: You need use `UIPresentationController` for that

Answer (score 0):

Issues based on navigation check your code.

```
or use that another way

HubViewController* vc = [HubViewController socialHubViewController];
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 3.0;
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
    [vc.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:^{
        NSLog(@"vc: presented");
    }];


    //UIViewController *topVc = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
```